# My 'combination generator' does not return anything after given input

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I am fairly new to the more 'intermediate' concepts in python. To recap what I've 'learned', I decided to make a combination generator. Basically, you give some input then it should return every combination of it. (e.g. I type in 'mark' and it should return 'kram', 'makr' etc.)

But I suspect that there's a problem with the 'combinations' function, I cant quite figure it out why.

```
from itertools import combinations


def combo_generator():
    user_string = {}
    for l in input("Enter a string for combo: "):
        combo = combinations(user_string, 8)
        user_string[l] = 1

    if user_string[l] >= 8:
        print("Too much strings! Enter less than 10 letters.")
        combo_generator()

    else:
        print(list(combo))


combo_generator()
```

Because here is the broken output:

```
Enter a string for combo: "mark"
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Any help will do. Thanks.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: I'll read them. Thank you

Comment: It actually helped!

Comment: It helped. Thanks, just gotta refine my code.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `input()` is a `str`, and when you call `for i in str`, like in `for l in input("Enter a string for combo: "):`, you process each character separately.

And as the itertools docs specify, `The number of items returned is n! / r! / (n-r)! when 0 <= r <= n or zero when r > n.`. Your `n=1` and `r=8`, therefore you observe empty arrays.

I believe you probably expected `input()` to be a bunch of words separated by spaces, if that's the case, you may wanna change your code to:

```
 for l in input("Enter a string for combo: ").split(" "):
     combo = combinations(user_string, 8)
```

but keep in mind that your words must be at least 8 characters long (and even then, it wouldn't be very cool of a combination. You may want to look into `combinations_with_repetition()`).

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Comment: This is not accurate. Note that while the OP is doing `for l in input()` they still call `combinations(user_string, 8)`... The problem is much simpler than that: `len(user_string) = 4` so there are no combinations of that string with 8 elements...

Comment: A solution in a similar question worked. I just gotta work on the 'letter detector' to avoid any crashes because of too much combinations.